# Factory method that returns generic instance

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base service class with virtual method that sets the properties of an object and returns that object.
Then i have one more service which derived from the base service and also overrides the base method. In overriden method, the derived service executes `base.DowWork()` to set common properties, and then also sets additional properties.
So based on articles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723648/how-to-inherit-method-but-with-different-return-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048884/c-overriding-return-types) I was able to do this using generics.

```
    public interface IResult
    {
    }

    public class BaseResult : IResult
    {
        public string CommonProperties { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdditionalResult : BaseResult
    {
        public string AdditionalProperties { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IService<T> where T : IResult
    {
        T DoWork();
    }

    public class BaseService<T> : IService<T> where T : BaseResult, new()
    {
        public virtual T DoWork()
        {
            var t = new T();

            t.CommonProperties = "Some Value";

            return t;
        }
    }
    public class AdditionalService : BaseService<AdditionalResult>
    {
        public override AdditionalResult DoWork()
        {
            var addtionalResult = base.DoWork();

            addtionalResult.CommonProperties = "Override value that was set by BaseService";
            addtionalResult.AdditionalProperties = "Set additional properties";

            return addtionalResult;
        }
    }
```

So far so good
Now i want to create a Factory method that will return the instance of a service based on some type. The application will use the factory to get service instance and call DoWork()  like below

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var factory = new MyFactory();
            var service = factory.GetService(0);
            var iresult = service.DoWork();

            // do something here with IResult              
        }
    }
```

below is the factory method

```
public class MyFactory
{
    public IService<IResult> GetService(int someType)
    {
        if (someType == 0)
        {
            return (IService<IResult>)new BaseService<BaseResult>();
        }

        if (someType == 1)
        {
            return (IService<IResult>)new AdditionalService();
        }

        // note I may have more types and services here. But for simplicity  i am using only 2

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

However i am not able to figure out what should be the signature of this factory method? Based on suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963259/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-xxx-to-t) I'm casting service instance but while executing the application I am getting runtime exception

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'BaseService 1[BaseResult]' to
>   type 'IService 1[IResult]'

if i don't cast the service instance in the Factory then i get compile time error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'BaseService' to
>   'IService'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See SO question [Understanding Covariant and Contravariant interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2720046/1260204).

You want to use covariance (`out` keyword). If you add it to your `IService` interface generic type it works as expected.

```
public interface IService<out T> where T : IResult
```

*I know SO prefers not to post links but I can't possibly write anything more or better than already [answered in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2720046/1260204).*

Comment: one of the link I provided above `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723648/how-to-inherit-method-but-with-different-return-type` says `No, the feature you mentioned is called return type covariance. It's not supported in C#.`

Comment: @LP13 - in your linked example it will not work because there is no common type being returned. In this case the return type should implement `IResult` which is ok, any type that implements IService should have a member that returns a type that implements IResult.

Comment: thanks that worked. and sorry for reposting answered question

Comment: @LP13 - No worries!